# How to automate the mail using shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I Need to Automate the script to get a mail. Example when we are running shell script  all the files are present or not then if present in mail need to get the message files are present else xxxxxxxxx.csv files alone not present please check .I need to write the script like this, please suggest.

Regards,
Sindhu

Comment: Which files where what? Incomprehensible. Question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi Robert, here  my query is how to automate the mail,Example In server 1 have i have automated to get files and alter need to automate the workfow... if files are not present in respective directories then workflow should not run.. in mail i should get like file a is not persent ....

Comment: You want the script to send an email about missing files?  Is the mail system running, you just want to know how to send email from a script?

Comment: What particular part of the script are you having a problem with? Testing for file existence? Generating the email body text?

Comment: Yeah i need to know the missing files and i need to now how to send such mail from script too

Comment: @ Forquare i need to Generating the email body

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, but from what I can make out, you're trying to run something periodically and want to get an email notification when something goes wrong, right?

If so, just make your shell script print error messages, and run it from cron; cron will automatically send you an email if a script produces any output. For more information on how to so, run `man crontab` and `man 5 crontab`, and read that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if_files(){
    for f do command <"$f" &&
          set -- "$@" "$f"
          shift
    done; printf present:\\t%s\\n "$@"
}   2>&1
```

For sending `mail` from the shell you can use `mail`, but you'll need a properly configured [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent).

Many programs will send your unix user account an email, but this might very well end up in *dead_letter* if you've not configured this correctly. Among these are `cron`, as has been mentioned, but there is also `at`, and even `ex` or `vi` can do so, both of which can run shell scripts.

You can use the above function with a standard `mail` client like:

```
if_files ./* |
mail -s file_check you@domain.com
```

Comment: Why the function? Is this not the same as `ls -1 ./*|mail -s file_check you@domain.com`?

Comment: @Lambert - no, it is not the same. as run, maybe so, but the `<` open will also complain for files which are not readable by the user that runs it.